# Как исправить Permission denied при попытке создать процесс на устройстве через приложение?

Tags: android, файловая-система, android-permissions

У меня результатом этого кода:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("arescam", "-a", "https://demo.mysite.ru/ca/", "-k");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process pr = builder.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
while (reader.readLine() != null) Log.d("PROCESSLOG", reader.readLine());
```

Является невыполненная команда и сообщение из лога:

```
D/PROCESSLOG: sh: cat: /sys/class/net/eth0/address: Permission denied
error: macaddr is null
```

Команду я посылаю stb приставке, на которой запускаю приложение.

Параметры доступа к папке **/sys** такие:

```
dr-xr-xr-x  12 root   root         0 2019-04-05 21:26 sys
```

На другой приставке, на которой всё работает, те же самые параметры доступа, но всё работает и нет сообщения о том, что нет доступа к папке **/sys**

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким или есть идеи с чем это может быть связано и как решить?

Comment: а причем здесь права на директорию? конкретно на этот файл какие права?

Comment: Только для чтения... -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2019-04-05 21:23 /sys/class/net/eth0/address. Я сейчас пытаюсь как-нибудь запустить этот процесс с "su", но пока безуспешно... Сделал для этого файла chmod 777 через терминал и больше ошибки не возникало, спасибо за наводку

Comment: достаточно было сделать `chmod +x`